# Проблемы юзабилити в JavaScript на сайте

Tags: javascript

Добрый день!

Есть небольшой JavaScript. Событие происходит так: 
Жму на блок(не div), их всего 4, открывается страница с html+css+php+mysql. Когда выбираю второй блок, там страница с опросом, жму на "ДА", JavaScript возвращает на первый блок с перезагрузкой страницы, что не удобно пользоваться.

В общем так, сижу на втором блоке, там опрос, отвечают на несколько вопросов, так чтобы не возвращала на первый блок, а оставался там до тех пор, пока не нажму на третий или первый блок.

html-код:

```
 table width="90%" height="2%" align="center">
 <tr class="header_menu">
 <th width="25%" scope="col" class="header_menu_a" onclick="OpenOne()"><h class="header_text">Первый</h></th>
 <th width="25%" scope="col" class="header_menu_a" onclick="OpenTwo()"><h class="header_text">Второй Тестирование</h></th>
 <th width="25%" scope="col" class="header_menu_a" onclick="OpenThree()"><h class="header_text">Третий</h></th>
 <th width="25%" scope="col" class="header_menu_a" onclick="OpenFour()"><h class="header_text">Вход в систему БД</h><br />*ссылка доступна сотрудникам</th>

 </tr>
 </table>
 <table width="90%" height="270" border="0" align="center">
 <tr>
 <th height="90%" scope="col"id="OpenOne" style="display:block;" class="ver_normal_red_lft"><? include 'body-pic/blood_city.php'?>
 </th>
 <th height="90%" scope="col"id="OpenTwo" style="display:none;"> <? include 'body-pic/test.php'?>
 </th>
 <th height="90%" scope="col"id="OpenThree" style="display:none;"> <? include 'body-pic/3a.php'?>
 </th>
 <th height="90%" scope="col"id="OpenFour" style="display:none;"> <? include 'body-pic/4a.php'?>
 </th>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

JavaScript

```
function OpenFour(){
$('#OpenFour').show();
$('#OpenThree').hide();
$('#OpenOne').hide();
$('#OpenTwo').hide();
}
function OpenThree(){
$('#OpenFour').hide();
$('#OpenThree').show();
$('#OpenTwo').hide();
$('#OpenOne').hide();
}
function OpenTwo(){
$('#OpenOne').hide();
$('#OpenTwo').show();
$('#OpenThree').hide();
$('#OpenFour').hide();
}
function OpenOne(){
$('#OpenOne').show();
$('#OpenThree').hide();
$('#OpenTwo').hide();
$('#OpenFour').hide();
}
```

Как видно, источник - подключаемые внешние модули или страницы.

Answer (score 1):

Что делает кнопка "ДА"? Насколько я понимаю, она вызывает `submit` формы. В таком случае нужно либо отменять `submit`, например, прописав `onclick='return false;'`, либо сохранять какой блок был открыт у пользователя на клиенте.